# Share posts on LinkedIn using Oauth2.0

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have a post containing document URL and post image URL. I am able to post the article with either document URL or post image URL but need help to post article with both document and post image URL.

I tried to create post using Create an Article or URL Share request body provided in docs: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context#create-an-article-or-url-share

But how to provide both image and document URL for that article?

```
final String finalTitle = title;
        final String finalMessage = message;
        String media = Mediatext;
        String finalBackUrl = backurl;
        Description description = new Description();
        description.setText(finalMessage);
        Title titleObj = new Title();
        titleObj.setText(finalTitle);
        List<Medium> mediumList = new ArrayList<>();
        Medium medium = new Medium();
        medium.setStatus("READY");
        medium.setDescription(description);
        medium.setOriginalUrl(finalBackUrl);
        medium.setTitle(titleObj);
        mediumList.add(medium);
        Visibility visibility = new Visibility();
        visibility.setComLinkedinUgcMemberNetworkVisibility("PUBLIC");
        SpecificContent specificContent = new SpecificContent();
        ShareCommentary shareCommentary = new ShareCommentary();
        ComLinkedinUgcShareContent comLinkedinUgcShareContent = new ComLinkedinUgcShareContent();
        comLinkedinUgcShareContent.setShareMediaCategory("ARTICLE");
        comLinkedinUgcShareContent.setMedia(mediumList);
        shareCommentary.setText(finalTitle);
        comLinkedinUgcShareContent.setShareCommentary(shareCommentary);
        specificContent.setComLinkedinUgcShareContent(comLinkedinUgcShareContent);
        LinkedInShareRequestModel requestModel = new LinkedInShareRequestModel();
        requestModel.setVisibility(visibility);
        requestModel.setAuthor("urn:li:person:" + linkedInURN); // todo get linkedin person urn
        requestModel.setLifecycleState("PUBLISHED");
        requestModel.setSpecificContent(specificContent);
        Call<LinkedInSharePostResponseModel> call = new ApiManager().getLinkedinService(this, Constants.ME_URL).sharePostOnLinkedIn("2.0.0", "Bearer " + linkedInAccessToken, requestModel);
```

Expected results: LinkedIn post with post image and document URL

Actual results: LinkedIn post with either post image or document URL